TypeScript generic parameters throwing error- "'?' expected"
I'm pretty new to TypeScript and trying to learn how to use generic type parameters. I have a function and a type that both accept type arguments, and I keep getting this error: '?' expected in the InputProps<T, K extends keyof T> portion of the function.
type InputProps<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    value: T[K]
}

function Input <T, K extends keyof T>({ value } : InputProps<T, K extends keyof T>) : void {
    console.log(value);
}

TS Playground Link

Could anyone explain why it expects that portion to be a conditional? I've searched around and can't seem to find an answer.

You've already defined the K type in the function signature as K extends keyof T. When used in the parameter definition, just use K
function Input <T, K extends keyof T>({ value } : InputProps<T, K>) : void {
    console.log(value);
}


Damn it was that simple. Thank you!!
